# split a single row of data into multiple unique rows into a new sheet to include headers as values and cell contents as values

Tags: excel, split, excel-2010, vba

I have found quite a lot of data splitting VBA code posts but none that splits it by contents and pulls in the header and puts the results into a new sheet (I need the original data to be left in its original state).

I have a spreadsheet that contains values in columns with a country as a header and I need to split each row into new rows in a new sheet with the country listed in a new column and the value from the same country column in the new row.

I want to ignore any country headers where the cell contents are blank as in the example with row 3.

This is a small example of the raw data:
[image: Raw Data Example]

And this is what I need the 3 rows to turn into:
[image: Required Results]

Although I am asking about VBA code I do not yet know how to write VBA and only adjust code that I have found on the internet to fit my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to coding VBA, i made a simple code with For and If, try to learn this functions.
I didn't declare every variable, try to declare them and learn about data types.
last_row and last_column are variables that can help a lot in Excel VBA, mainly to make dynamic spreadsheets

```
Sub test()
'Declare variables here
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet

'sht1 has the data and sht2 is the output Worksheet, you can change the names
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

last_row1 = sht1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
last_column = sht1.Cells(1, sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
x = 1

'Add header
sht2.Cells(1, 1) = "Company"
sht2.Cells(1, 2) = "Country"
sht2.Cells(1, 3) = "Status"
'Data add
For i = 2 To last_row1
'Assuming Company is in Column 1 or A
    For k = 2 To last_column
        'If cell is different from blank then write data
        If sht1.Cells(i, k) <> "" Then
        sht2.Cells(x + 1, 1) = sht1.Cells(i, 1)
        sht2.Cells(x + 1, 2) = sht1.Cells(1, k)
        sht2.Cells(x + 1, 3) = sht1.Cells(i, k)
        x = x + 1
        End If
    Next k
Next i

MsgBox "Data Updated"
End Sub
```

Next time, try to learn some coding and post your code.

Comment: I do usually try to do some of the work myself but in this instance I really struggled to find anything that was anywhere near what I was trying to achieve.  I will try harder next time.  This works beautifully so thank you very much.  I have marked as correct answer.